# Spring Hateoas @EnableEntityLinks does not provide EntityLinks bean (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Spring HATEOAS, it has `@EnableEntityLinks` enabled. The application has a mvc-controller containing a field `@Autowired EntityLinks entityLinks`.

I expected that `@EnableEntityLinks` would provide the `EntityLinks` bean (according to: [Exposing and Managing Links with Spring HATEOAS](http://city81.blogspot.de/2013/06/exposing-and-managing-links-with-spring.html)), but I get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.hateoas.EntityLinks] found`

The application is a test application, so it is quite small:

Application.java:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableEntityLinks
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

CustomerController:

```
@Controller
@ExposesResourceFor(Customer.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/customers", produces = "application/json")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private EntityLinks entityLinks;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> customers() {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Customer>>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> customer(@PathVariable long id) {

        Customer customer = new Customer(id, "Testi");
        customer.add(this.entityLinks.linkToSingleResource(Customer.class, id));

        return new ResponseEntity<Customer>(customer, HttpStatus.OK);
    }       
}
```

Customer.java

```
public class Customer extends ResourceSupport {

    private Long id;
    private String firstName;

    public Customer(Long id, String firstName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }   

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- fuer @ExposesResourceFor benoetigt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

Exception:

```
2014-01-27 15:04:22.928  INFO 5036 --- [           main] .c.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/workspaces/Seedmatch33/gs-rest-hateoas-initial/target/classes/, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-web-1.0.0.RC1.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-1.0.0.RC1.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-1.0.0.RC1.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.0.0.RC1.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.0.0.RC1.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.5/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.5/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.5/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.13/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.0.13/logback-core-1.0.13.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.0.0.RC1.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.47/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/7.0.47/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.47.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/springframework/spring-web/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.3.1/jackson-databind-2.3.1.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.3.0/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.3.1/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/0.8.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/springframework/hateoas/spring-hateoas/0.8.0.RELEASE/spring-hateoas-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/springframework/spring-core/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/.m2repo/org/objenesis/objenesis/1.3/objenesis-1.3.jar]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.hateoas.EntityLinks test.CustomerController.entityLinks; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.hateoas.EntityLinks] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:658)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:355)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:920)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at Application.main(Application.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.hateoas.EntityLinks test.CustomerController.entityLinks; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.hateoas.EntityLinks] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.hateoas.EntityLinks] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Anywhere in your code, poms or config files do you have `Autwire` turned off or set to false (ex.  `annotation-config="false"`)?  Did you double check any missing JARs/WARs/etc.?

Comment: @Mohammad S. I dont have tuned of Autowire. The code in the question is EVERY THING I have (except the header and build section of the pom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure anywhere in your code, poms or config files you do not have `Autwire` turned off or set to false (ex. `annotation-config="false"`) This could very much cause an issue.

Also, double check any missing JARs/WARs/etc or missing annotations in any of your classes (ex.  `@EnableEntityLinks`).

Comment: Double checking helped. (I bang my head against the desk) There was an second Application class in the root package without @EnableEntityLinks annotation, and I always used that to start the application - and I even don't noticed

Comment: @Ralph woooh.  glad to help.  |=^]